# SwiftUI NavigationView in a MacOS behaving like iPhone

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI Sample App for MacOS and iOS with a NavigationView.
It behaves almost as expected.

What I would like to archive on the Mac:
If the width of the window gets (very) small, it shall behaves like an iPhone in portrait mode with only one Column in which the views are stacked.

```
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView{
      Master().navigationTitle("Master")
      Text("A").navigationTitle("Detail-A")
    }
  }
}

struct Master: View {
  var body: some View {
    VStack{
      NavigationLink("A"){Text("A").navigationTitle("Detail-A")}
      NavigationLink("B"){Text("B").navigationTitle("Detail-A")}
      NavigationLink("C"){Text("C").navigationTitle("Detail-A")}
      Spacer()
    }
    #if os(macOS)
    .buttonStyle(.link)
    #elseif os(macOS)
    .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
    #endif
    
  }
}
```

The Modifier **.navigationViewStyle(.stack)** is not available in MacOS and does not work on iPad.

How can I do that?

Comment: That’s not an available behavior for normal Mac apps. You could achieve it by using Catalyst, though.

Comment: (didn't downvote) I would pretty strongly recommend against this. It's not an available navigation style for a reason (it wasn't just forgotten): it's not what mac users are used to, and it wouldn't fit in with the rest of the platform. Plus, it doesn't really make sense to use, as stack-based navigation was invented specifically for the narrow screens of mobile devices, where traditional desktop UIs (inspector windows, wizards, master-detail views, multiple windows, etc simply don't work). It exists to solve a problem which simply doesn't exist on the mac.